# Iterating over selected features in QGIS Processing

Tags: qgis, python, vector, pyqgis, sextante

I used to be able to iterate over selected features using the following script in v2.0.

```
import processing
features = processing.getfeatures(layer)
for feature in features:
  #Do whatever you need with the feature
```

However, this doesn't seem to work when I upgraded my QGIS to v2.2. Is there any new way on how to iterate selected vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the solutions given in [Using processing algorithms from the console](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html):

But if you look at what's in the module (version 2.2):

```
import processing
dir(processing)
```

no more `getfeatures()` or `getFeatures()`

You can control this with a little function adapted from [Script de Python para filtrar por patrón de texto los métodos de Clases en PyQGIS](http://joseguerreroa.wordpress.com/2014/03/16/script-de-python-para-filtrar-por-patron-de-texto-los-metodos-de-clases-en-pyqgis/) de José Guerrero

```
import re
def get_patt(keyword, L):
    return [item for item in dir(L) if re.search(keyword,item)]
get_patt("getfeatures",processing)
[]
get_patt("getFeatures",processing)
[]
```

but there is:

```
get_patt("features",processing)
['features']
```

So the command is:

```
features = processing.features(layer)
```

But for me, it is easiest with:

without processing:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
```

with processing:

```
layer = processing.getObject("name_of_the_layer")
```

All the features:

```
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
     geom= feat.geometry()
     attr =feat.attributes()
```

Selected features only:

```
for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
     geom= feat.geometry()
     attr =feat.attributes()
```

and, for example, an "universal solution":

```
if layer.selectedFeatureCount():
     geom = [feat.geometry() for feat in layer.selectedFeatures()]
else:
     geom = [feat.geometry() for feat in layer.getFeatures()]
```

Comment: Thanks gene for your detailed reply. Indeed the recent version (v2.2) uses 'processing.features(layer)' instead of the old 'processing.getfeatures(layer)'. Many thanks!