# Finding intersection length between two polygons using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, geometry, intersection

I have two polygons and I want to find the intersection line length between these polygons.

```
for geom1, geom2 in itertools.permutations(selection, r=2):
    intersection =geom1.geometry().intersection(geom2.geometry())
```

It gives the boolean values as true/false. But I want to find the intersection length. How can I do that using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intersects` gives the boolean value True, False, `intersection` gives the geometry

If you use the `dir` function of Python

```
dir(intersection) 
['Error', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__geo_interface__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'addPart', 'addPartGeometry', 'addRing', 'adjacentVertices', 'area', 'asGeometryCollection', 'asMultiPoint', 'asMultiPolygon', 'asMultiPolyline', 'asPoint', 'asPolygon', 'asPolyline', 'asQPointF', 'asQPolygonF', 'asWkb', 'avoidIntersections', 'boundingBox', 'buffer', 'centroid', 'closestSegmentWithContext', 'closestVertex', 'closestVertexWithContext', 'combine', 'compare', 'contains', 'convertToMultiType', 'convertToType', 'convexHull', 'crosses', 'deletePart', 'deleteRing', 'deleteVertex', 'difference', 'disjoint', 'distance', 'equals', 'exportToGeoJSON', 'exportToWkt', 'fromMultiPoint', 'fromMultiPolygon', 'fromMultiPolyline', 'fromPoint', 'fromPolygon', 'fromPolyline', 'fromQPointF', 'fromQPolygonF', 'fromRect', 'fromWkb', 'fromWkt', 'insertVertex', 'interpolate', 'intersection', 'intersects', 'isGeosEmpty', 'isGeosEqual', 'isGeosValid', 'isMultipart', 'length', 'makeDifference', 'moveVertex', 'offsetCurve', 'overlaps', 'pointOnSurface', 'reshapeGeometry', 'rotate', 'simplify', 'smooth', 'splitGeometry', 'sqrDistToVertexAt', 'symDifference', 'touches', 'transform', 'translate', 'type', 'unaryUnion', 'validateGeometry', 'vertexAt', 'within', 'wkbSize', 'wkbType']
```

You find the `length` function (look also at [Using OGR Intersection Method Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107535/using-ogr-intersection-method-python/107550#107550) for the function `get_patt` or use the [see](https://github.com/inky/see) module)

```
from see import see 
b = see(intersection)
import re
[item for item in b if re.search("length",item)]
['.length()']
```

So the command is

```
intersection.length()

for geom1,geom2 in  itertools.combinations(selection, 2):
    if geom1.intersects(geom2):
       intersection = geom1.intersection(geom2)
       print intersection.exportToWkt()
u'MULTILINESTRING((481.58899999999999864 -222.97899999999992815, 481.58899999999999864 -265.54699999999996862), (481.58899999999999864 -265.54699999999996862, 433.38699999999994361 -386.36500000000000909), (433.38699999999994361 -386.36500000000000909, 319.91949270774443903 -369.28386986998305019))'
print intersection.length()
287.39250343267042
```

But be careful
- the intersection of two Polygons is never a simple LineString but a (Multi)Polygon
- if you want (Multi)LineStrings, you need to use the intersection of the Polygons Rings  (my reply in [Finding the common borders between polygons in the same shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95573/finding-the-common-borders-between-polygons-in-the-same-shapefile/95595#95595))
- in most cases,the result is a heterogeneous collections of geometric objects (look at [Shapely: Collections](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#collections))

Comment: from the MULTILINESTRING i want to get the coordinates. I want like this (3.24934170594707172 6.67189348518093706, 3.24929629918317087 6.67176343113283998)(3.24929629918317087 6.67176343113283998, 3.24925621546922283 6.67149461722516701).How can i do that.