# Method 'to_crs' to reproject with GeoPandas is missing

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to reproject data using GeoPandas' `to_crs` method but it seems to be missing. When I type `hasattr(gpd, 'to_crs')` I get FALSE. Also, when I type `dir(geopandas)` in the command prompt it doesn't appear in the list of attributes and methods.

```
>>> dir(geopandas)
['GeoDataFrame', 'GeoSeries', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package
__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_version', 'base', 'datasets', 'geodataframe', 'geopandas', 'geoseries', '
gpd', 'io', 'np', 'overlay', 'pd', 'plotting', 'points_from_xy', 'read_file', 'read_postgis', 'sjoin', 'tools']
```

I have reinstalled GeoPandas several times, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_crs` is a function at the GeoDataFrame level ([def to_crs() in geodataframe.py](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/39385a1fb92660aab982051db5f80cd39ae54750/geopandas/geodataframe.py)) or the GeoSerie level ([geoseries.py](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/961a78d24303033823f8dfbabe8b6da0b85ce20d/geopandas/geoseries.py))

Using a function adapted from a script [Script de Python para filtrar por patrón de texto los métodos de Clases en PyQGIS](http://joseguerreroa.wordpress.com/2014/03/16/script-de-python-para-filtrar-por-patron-de-texto-los-metodos-de-clases-en-pyqgis/) de José Guerrero (already used in [Iterating over selected features in QGIS Processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/iterating-over-selected-features-in-qgis-processing/98077#98077))

```
import geopandas
import re
def get_patt(keyword, L):
    return [item for item in dir(L) if re.search(keyword,item)]
print(get_patt("to_crs",geopandas))
[] # nothing at this level
# but
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame, GeoSerie
print(get_patt("to_crs",GeoDataFrame))
['to_crs']
print(get_patt("to_crs",GeoSeries))
['to_crs']
```

Thus, at the GeoDataFrame level:

```
shapef =  geopandas.read_file("a_shape.shp")
type(shapef)
<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
print(get_patt("to_crs",shapef))
['to_crs']
```

And you can use `shapef.to_crs()`

You can also use the [see](https://pypi.org/project/see/) module (dir for humans)

```
from see import see
see(shapef).filter('*to_crs*')
.to_crs()
```